# How Do I Get Out of a Breaking Point Submission?

Tags: wwe-13

I haven't played WWE '12 and the instructions for WWE '13 are terrible.  There is also no in-game interactive tutorial, so I'm lost as to how I can get out of a BREAKING POINT submission once someone puts me in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the way to break out of a BREAKING POINT submission is, literally, to mash all of the face buttons.  On a PS3 this would be triangle, square, x, and circle.  The easiest way is to hold your thumb over all of them and quickly roll it back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

On Xbox you bash X and A. When the screen starts shaking the BREAKING POINT bar goes faster so it's easier to win.